# How do I do the equivalent of web3.eth.getAccounts() for Nethereum?

Tags: ethereum, web3js, nethereum

I have this working in js to give me the address of the logged-in Metamask user, but I would like to do it using Nethereum. Could someone tell me the equivalent to this with Nethereum?

```js
var accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
console.log(accounts)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible, because MetaMask is accessible only in the web frontend (JavaScript/TypeScript) and .NET does not run within a web browser.

To get the user address on the server side securely, you need to ask user to sign a message with MetaMask and then extract the address from the message signature.

Comment: Hello Mikko, Can you please say what do you mean by "extract the address" ? is the public address or private key you are taking?. If you meant public address can i sign transaction with the public address in backend?

Comment: You can only know the address the user is using. You can not o anything with that address, because that's the whole point of a blockchain.

Comment: Or.... blockchain eliminates the ability of middlemen to do actions on behalf of them without their explicit permission.

Answer (score -1):

for Nethereum right now we dont have any   direct support that it can access Metamask , so in netherium you can only access account using private key or seed phrase

Like this below

```
 var account = new Account(privateKey);
 var publicAddressOfTheAboveAccount = account.Address;
```

Check the below link if you want to use metamask using Nethereum.Metamask.Blazor to access metamask account instance

[checkthislink](https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum.Metamask.Blazor)